# Unable to Check Camera FlashLight mode

Tags: java, android, flash, camera

I am working on Flash Alert Application. i got stuck in one problem. i want to check if camera torch light is on already. i did a research found answers but not solved my problem.

> Here is my code for check flashlight state;

```
try
                    {
                        camera = Camera.open();
                        onParams = camera.getParameters();
                        if (onParams != null)
                            {
                                Log.e("flash mode", onParams.getFlashMode());
                                if (onParams.getFlashMode().equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
                                    {
                                        camera.stopPreview();
                                        camera.release();
                                        return true;
                                    }
                            }
                        onParams.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        camera.startPreview();

                        return false;

                    }
                catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return true;
                    }
```

to check this me On system torchlight by widget of mobile. and run this code it gave me log value "flash mode","off". so if case never call. 
i am Testing this on Galaxy s3 Android 4.3, API level 19.

> here is my manifest permissions

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Camera Requirement -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

    <!-- Camera Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

> please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: sow the question is how to know  if the flashlight is on or off?

Comment: Ben_Gratvol can u give me more detail answer i cant understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a boolean variable and set it to true if when flash light is on and off when flash light is off. And with the help of that boolean variable you can check the status of your flash light. Hope this helps.